# Shift an image horizontally

Tags: graphics, plot

Is there generically a latex command which allows to shift images horizontally by a prescribed amount of cm for example?

Comment: `\includegraphics` has no spacing logic at all, it is just positioned like a letter, so you can put `\hspace*{1cm}` before it for example.

Comment: `\hspace*{2cm}`?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! In which point of the code should I insert it? Before \begin{figure}?

Comment: no before the image.